# How to print largest number in a list which also has other elements next to it in the same string

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that takes in a list with objects and next to the object there is also a number. I want to print the object which has the largest number next to it.
One idea is to look for the last value in the string by using the `[-1]`, however I quickly realised that wouldnt work if the number was more than 1-digit.
I have also written this code, however this just returns the last element in the list.

```
list_of_words = ["car 1", "telephone 3", "bottle 10", "laptop 8", "window 12", "headphones 5"]

def autocomplete_freq_words():
    for word in list_of_words:
        return max(list_of_words)

print(autocomplete_freq_words())
```

Basically, for list_of_words and I want print the word "window".

Comment: Use regular expressions to pull out the numbers. E.g. [0-9]+ should match one or more numbers. Then sort them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`rsplit(maxsplit=1)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to split on whitespace and select the last element as your comparison key from each list element.

```
print(
    max(list_of_words, key=lambda x: int(x.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1]))
)
```

**Output:**

```
window 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list and then take the last element

```
def autocomplete_freq_words(list_of_words):
    list_of_words.sort(key=lambda w: int(w.split()[-1]))
    return list_of_words[-1]

list_of_words = ["car 1","telephone 3","bottle 10", "laptop 8","window 12","headphones 5"]
print(autocomplete_freq_words(list_of_words))
```